# SpriteKit making 2 SKShapeNodes stick together?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to find a way to make two SKShapeNodes stick together when I drag one close to another. Is there a way to do this with the SpriteKit API?

For example: two magnetic blocks that stick together to form a longer block when I move one block close to another.

Thanks!

Comment: In iOS 8, Apple added some new physics functionality to SpriteKit.  I am not an expert in their use, but you might want to check out [SKFieldNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKFieldNode_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKFieldNode/magneticField). Specific to your example, they have a Magnetic Field node.  Many others, as well.  I should also point out they demo them in the [WWDC 2014 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) "What's New in SpriteKit". Good luck!

Comment: Oh, and you can check out Apple's Guide to [Simulating Physics](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Physics/Physics.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the position of the 2 SKSpriteNodes in question in the update method. When they have reached the desired distance, you can make one a child of the other. Alternately, you can create an invisible node, covering both SKSpriteNodes and make them children of the invisible node.